# I can not use the theil sen estimator in R

Tags: r, regression

I have installed the theil sen estimator package mblm using the following command:

```
install.packages("mblm")
```

it shows:

```
package ‘mblm’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
```

but when I trie to use it, I receive the following error:

```
Error: could not find function "mblm"
```

what could be the problem? Did I install the right package?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a programming based query, and would be better addressed in SO

Comment: Did you load the package? I replicated the response from [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13685), it worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely [R FAQ 7.30](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#I-installed-a-package-but-the-functions-are-not-there):

> To actually use the package, it needs to be loaded using library().